# How to deduce this PDE from the ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose for $\xi=ct-x$ and $\psi=\psi(\xi)$ we have the ODE
$$
\partial_{\xi\xi}\psi-c\partial_\xi\psi+f'(V(\xi))\psi=0.\quad (1)
$$

Now, let

\begin{align*}
V_i=V_i(x,t):=&V((-1)^i(x-d_i(t))-ct),\\
\psi_i=\psi_i(x,t):=&(-1)^i\psi((-1)^i(x-d_i(t))-ct).
\end{align*}

> > It is claimed that
> >     $$
> > -\partial_t\psi_i=\partial_{xx}\psi_i+f'(V_i)\psi_i-\partial_x\psi_i d_i'\qquad (2)
> > $$
> >     since $\psi$ satisfies $(1)$.

**I do not see this!** Thus my question is: How to get (2)?

I think it might be useful to distinguish the cases that $i$ is even and odd.

For $i$ even, we have
$$
\psi_i=\psi(x-d_i(t)-ct)\quad\text{and}\quad V_i=V(x-d_i(t)-ct).
$$

For $i$ odd, we have
$$
\psi_i=-\psi(x+d_i(t)-ct)\quad\text{and}\quad V_i=V(-x+d_i(t)-ct).
$$

**Attempt:**
I tried to use that, for even $i$, the argument of $\psi_i$ and $V_i$ is
$$
y:=x-d_i(t)-ct=-\xi-d_i(t).
$$
So maybe one can use scaling and shifting, i.e.
$$
-y-d_i(t)=\xi,
$$
to bring everything back to variable $\xi$ in order to be able to use equation $(1)$?
But I have no idea if this helps or makes sense

Comment: Note that $\psi$ is a function of a single variable so let's get rid of the confusion with $\xi$ and it's relation to $x$ and $t$ and simply call it $y$. Then the first equation reads $\psi''(y)  - c\psi'(y) + \ldots = 0$ so its the second derivative of $\psi$ minus ... and so on. Now if $\psi_i = \psi(x-ct)$ then $(\psi_i)_t = -c\psi'(x-ct)$ and $(\psi_i)_x = \psi'(x-ct)$ and so on. Prove (2) by showing that it's satisfied by evaluating it using this and comparing to the given ODE (it will reduce to the same ODE evaluated at $y = x - d_i - ct$)

Comment: I do not see your point, because $\psi_i$ is not $\psi(x-ct)$.

Comment: It was a simplified example to avoid typing. Do the same thing with $y= x - ct - d_i(t)$ (so the time-derivative is now $(-c-d_i'(t))\psi'$ and so on)

Comment: You have a PDE for $\psi_i$ (the one you wanted to show). I was suggesting that you verify that this PDE is indeed satisfied by computing all $\psi_i$ terms in terms of $\psi'$ and compare the left and the right hand side using the ODE to show that it's indeed true.

Comment: Let $y:=x-ct-d_i(t)$. What I get is the equation $$-c\psi'(y)-d_i'(t)\psi'(y)=\psi''(y)+f(V(y))-\psi'(y)d_i'(t)$$. Hence, adding $d_i'(t)\psi'(y)$ on both sides, I get the equation $$-c\psi'(y)=\psi''(y)+f(V(y))$$.

Comment: Which you know is true (it's exactly the same as the ODE you are given). You can do the same derivation in general with the $(-1)^i$ factor and you get the same result (that it's true). You can also if you want turn this derivation on it's head to *derive* the PDE from the ODE.

Comment: Not completely the same, because the argument is $y$ instead of $\xi$.

Comment: That was my original point. The variable is just a label here, don't be confused by the letter that is used. For example if $f(x) = x^2$ then $f''(x) = 2$. But I can also say that $f''(t) = 2$. $t$ and $x$ here are just labels.

Comment: I think I am too stupi. Its not absolutely clear to me why the ODE which holds for the argument $\xi$ also holds for the argument $y$ which is $y=-\xi-d_i(t)$.

Comment: Let's try to look at the ODE as a function. Let's call $g(\xi) = \psi''(\xi) - c\psi'(\xi) + f'(V(\xi)) \psi(\xi)$. You know that since $\psi$ satisfy the ODE that we have $g(\xi) = 0$ for all $\xi$ right? So $g(2) = 0$ and $g(10) = 0$. If you agree on this then you will see that we can take $\xi$ to be any number you want and it will still hold.

Comment: I agree that $g(\xi)=0$ for all $\xi$.

Comment: I think that it depends on the domain of $\psi, \psi',\psi''$ etc (on the domain of $g$, respectively). For example $\xi$ can be in the domain but $y$ not. But maybe I am talking nonsense.

Comment: The domain here is all real numbers so it's not an issue. Or if it wasn't then this would only be a restriction on the domain (the allowed $x$ and $t$) in the PDE you get.

Comment: If this is the case, I am fine.